# spring security role-based needed for full stack app?

Tags: spring-security, role-base-authorization

I am implementing a basic login app. here are the features:

1. Upon successful login, there should be a welcome page that shows the name, username and role (manager/user).
2. If the user has a manager role, the welcome page will have a link to access a restricted webpage.
3. This restricted webpage can only be accessed by a manager role and not by other user roles.
4. implement logout functionality.
5. If the userid or password is not valid, I should remain at the login page with an error message "Invalid userid or password".
6. All data should be stored in a database.
7. The application should demonstrate MVC pattern...

my schema:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwLEO.jpg)

i am using react js for the front end. i build the backend using spring security with the role-based authorization where certain url can be accessed by certain role. i already do a testing on backend end using postman where i try to access /restricted and it responded with 401 if i use ROLE-USER instead of ROLE-MANAGER by using the mvcMatchers(). now the confusing part is the frontend

i noticed i can do all the necessary validation on the front end. i dont even need to do mvcMatcher() on the backend as i can just load the userdetails and roles and ask react to validate for me! hell, i dont even need to use role-based authorisation. i just need to add extra field in user table named "role" and use that to check for item 3 and display the role on item 1. i just need 1 table, not 3. i can even ask react to redirect to /login if user is trying to access /welcome without login, or disable /unauthorised if user role is USER.

but i dont feel right about this way. i'm confused.

a. whats the best approach?

b. is role-based only applicable to rest-api services, not full stack app? from what i see front end can do ALL validation

[back end repo](https://github.com/norulshahlam/login-app-backend)
[front end repo](https://github.com/norulshahlam/login-app-frontend)

Answer (score 0):

a. The Best approach is to have authorization at the back-end level because your React front-end is not the only way to access the back-end. If the back-end doesn't have authorization implemented, then even if you have validation on the front-end, a malicious user can use any other HTTP client to access the back-end without authorization.

b. Role-based authorization is applicable in all scenarios in which you want to allow access to resources based on user roles, no matter which stack is used.

Comment: what if i use jwt? wil that solve the problem? even if malicious user is using other http client to access backend, it still need jwt right. 
also, if every request requires a body containing credentials, how would the person be able to bypass that?

Comment: Jwt is used to authenticate or in other words identify a user, without role-based authorization at the back-end, someone with the user's role jwt can access the resource intended to be accessed by a manager.

Comment: so i need both then? or atleast i need role based authorisation

Comment: You're right, yes. Back-end authorization is necessary for your use-case and Front-end validation for better User-Experience.